# How to redirect current page to another in opera mini mobile?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to redirect user in opera mini mobile browser by using window.location.Its working fine in other browser except opera. If i use document.location then page goes to endless loading and page not load.So how to redirect user using javascript in opera mini.

Comment: check javascript is enable or not on browser

Comment: Hi joseph I am trying to redirection on some condition.how to implement your ans in such situation just like below
if(thumb=='bthumb'){
window.location='main.php?f=3267939&sname=bb&thumb=bthumb&page=9'}

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid is a matter of Opera Mini configuration.
Check if redirection is disabled in `Opera > Preferences > Advanced > Network`
I'm not sure you can override this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that Opera is re-loading the current page is because the
navigation that is requested by clicking the link is not being cancelled
by the onClick handler (except in IE where window.event.returnValue is
meaningful). Opera is probably starting to navigate to the new page when
you set the location.href, but is then acting on the HREF attribute of
the link. (Presumably Netscape/mozilla regards the first instruction to
change pages as an excuse to terminate activity on the current page, so
it does not go on to do the navigation specified in the HREF attribute).

The solution is to explicitly return false from the onClick code. Either
by having the function return false and changing the code in the
attribute to:
    onclick="return OnClickLocation('clickTest.html');"
or just adding return false at the end of the attribute:

```
onclick="OnClickLocation('clickTest.html');return false;"
```